# Numerical Analysis converging sequence question

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

1. Show that the sequence $p=10^{-2n}$ converges to zero with order $2$.
2. How many steps, $n$, will it take before this sequence is within $10^{-8}$ of zero?
3. Construct a sequence that converges with order $4$.

Answer (score 0):

For (1) and (3), you need to use the definition:

**Definition:** We say that the sequence converges with order $q$ to $L$ for $q>1$ if

$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{|x_{k+1}-L|}{|x_k-L|^q} = \mu \,\big|\; \mu > 0.$$